# clear form input textarea when a tag is clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, input, field

I have a form with some tags under it. When you click each tag it enters into the field fine but at the moment I have a default value in that field and want it to disappear when you click either one of the tags. At the moment it works but it makes every other tag disappear when you click another tag to add to the field.

The form default value reads "Please click on the tags to choose what area you like." When you click on a tag that disappears and then the field gets populated with the selected tags underneath that.

Has anyone got any ideas how I would do this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: some code would be really helpful, preferably in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you implementing your default text?  Could you use the HTML5 "placeholder" attribute to store your default text?

**UPDATE**
If I understood you correctly is this what you are trying to do, or something like it, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZM8v/)

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean?

Comment: Please do not forget to mark this post as the answer, thanks.

Comment: chmeers mreyeros, sorry about that.